# How to create the callback url in iPhone application for flickr?

Tags: ios, flickr

i am working with an iPhone application in which  i have to call flicker api from my application with the help of oath protocol.i am calling the flicker api's but i didn't get how to create callback url for my application.Please guide my how to create the callback url for my application so that after authentication flicker send me back with help of my callback url.

Answer (score 0):

Flickr uses  `OAuth Core 1.0 Revision A`. This protocol is fully described here: http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/

Look at `Appendix A - Protocol Example` (http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#anchor41). On third step is answer for your question - in `Appendix A.3.  Requesting User Authorization` (http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#anchor44)

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your suggestion,i am going through the tutorial but i didn't get how will i create my own callback url?

Comment: You can to try to create some dummy URL. When server responses with redirection to this URL, you will be able to parse redirect-URL. This redirect-URL must contain as parts your callback URL and access token, so you can recognize this type of server's answer and then - obtain necessary token.